# How can I remove the specific prefix for files in one directory with fish

Tags: fish

I want to loop files in one directory and then remove the specific prefix in batch, how can i do that using fish shell?

Answer (score 1):

Assumed you have a directory like this:

```
mkdir /tmp/example
touch /tmp/example/prefix-file(seq 9)
```

Then you can do the following:

```
for i in /tmp/example/prefix-*
  mv $i (echo $i | sed 's/prefix-//')
end
```

There are many different ways to do this, but I think this is the most straight forward way.